# Incomplete type is not allowed in struct constructor

Tags: c++

I got this error when try to do this:

```
#include <iostream>
using namespace std;
struct VertexStatus
{
private:
    int _CurrentStatus;

public:
    static VertexStatus Discovered = new VertexStatus(1); //incomplete type is not allowed
    VertexStatus(int iStatus)
    {
        this->_CurrentStatus = iStatus;
    }
};
```

Is there something wrong?

Comment: You do not want to be using `new` here.

Comment: Plenty is wrong, including the fact that you seem to confuse Java and C++. See NPE's answer on how to *properly* do what you're trying to do.

Comment: @juanchopanza Possibly missed with formatting/copy/paste :)

Comment: How do you suppose you can define something that contains that something? You get infinite recursion.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

Move the initialization out of the class body:

```
struct VertexStatus
{
    ...
    static VertexStatus Discovered; // declaration
    ...
};

VertexStatus VertexStatus::Discovered(1); // definition (with initializer)
```

If the class is declared in a header file, place the last line (the definition) into the corresponding `.cpp` file.

Notice that I've removed the `new`: it returns a pointer and there are no pointers involved in this code.

Answer (score -2):

The size of `VertexStatus` is not known until after it has been fully declared, which it has not been inside its own definition.

Instead initialize the static variable after the declaration, like this:

```
struct VertexStatus {
    static VertexStatus Discovered;
    // ... other stuff
};

VertexStatus::Discovered = new VertexStatus(1);
```

If this is inside a header file, you need to put the last line inside it's corresponding .cpp file.

Comment: `Discover` isn't a pointer - this code, as is, doesn't make sense and would not compile.